# Defer connection to datasources defined in application.conf

Tags: database, scala, configuration, playframework, app-config

Say I have a database called "awesome" which is located on a live server and at the same time duplicated on a staging server for testing. My web app is based on Play 2.1.1 using Scala.
So I have these datasources defined in my *application.conf* file:

```
db.awesome-test.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.awesome-test.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.1.1/awesome"
db.awesome-test.user=mr_awesome_tester
db.awesome-test.password=justtesting

db.awesome-live.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.awesome-live.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/awesome"
db.awesome-live.user=mr_awesome
db.awesome-live.password=omgthisisawesome
```

Depending on what environment I am on, I would like to use either `DB.withConnection("awesome-test")` or `DB.withConnection("awesome-live")`. I am controlling this via another value in my config; so I e.g. put `environment=awesome-live` in there and then get the respective connection string via `Play.configuration`.

Now, the problem is that apparently play attempts to create a DB connection to each datasource defined in the config right away. A) This fails depending on which environment I am on. E.g. on the staging machine I will get something like this (pic is only a mock-up of course) because the live DB is not reachable:

[image]

...although it is completely unnecessary to try to connect to that DB, because it will never be used in this environment. B) Even if the connection would work, of course it would not be feasable to create two connections (live and testing) when only one of the two is ever needed.

Is there a way to tell Play to defer/postpone creation of the DB connection until it is actually needed (e.g. when `DB.getConnection("...")` or `DB.withConnection("...")` or something is called for that datasource)?
I am thinking something like `db.awesome-live.deferCreation=true`.

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you have two ways of doing this.

Everything is explained at the Play! Documentation: [Additional configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ProductionConfiguration)

#### Specifying alternative configuration file

`test.conf`

```
db.awesome.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.awesome.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.1.1/awesome"
db.awesome.user=mr_awesome_tester
db.awesome.password=justtesting
```

`live.conf`

```
db.awesome.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.awesome.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/awesome"
db.awesome.user=mr_awesome
db.awesome.password=omgthisisawesome
```

In code you always use `DB.withConnection("awesome")`.

Start the application with

```
$ start -Dconfig.resource=test.conf
```

or

```
$ start -Dconfig.resource=live.conf
```

#### Overriding specific configuration keys

In your case that means:

```
$ start -Ddb.awesome-live.deferCreation=true
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Especially the *include "application.conf"* functionality seems perfect for my scenario. I'll simply define the environment-specific stuff in separate files without having to duplicate the config that both environments have in common.

Comment: @alexander.biskop Yes, that is definitely the way to do it!